# Can $1+\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$ be prime for all $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, products

This is inspired by
[Show, by computing several values, that there are composite numbers in this sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910011/show-by-computing-several-values-that-there-are-composite-numbers-in-this-sequ)

Is there an increasing sequence 
of positive integers
$(a_i)|_{i=1}^{\infty}
$
such that
$1+\prod_{i=1}^n a_i
$
is prime for all $n$?

I have no idea how to solve this
or whether such a sequence exists
or not.

I would be satisfied
with an existence proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By (a special case of) [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), for any given $m$ there are infinitely many $k$ for which $km+1$ is prime.

So, once you have a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ with the desired property, take
$m=a_1a_2\cdots a_n$ and choose $a_{n+1}$ to be a value of $k$ such that $k>a_n$ and $km+1$ is prime.

Comment: Yup. I thought of that too. Accepted.